# how to scan strings with white spaces and print them C

Tags: c, string

I have to read a string, to concatenate with another and print the result
I tried this code:

```
int main(){
    char s= "StackOverflow ";
    char ss[100]; 
    fgets(ss,100,stdin);
    // i know i can use strcat but i don't want it here
    printf("%s%s",s,ss);
    return 0;
}
```

the ss is "is the best site for learning things!"
Some help?

Comment: Please look at the compiler warnings.

Comment: You really gotta use char* s for holding a string "Stackoverflow". You are trying to hold a string in a char.

Comment: `char s= ...` --> `const char *s= ...`

Comment: the online compiler gcc 4.9.2, no warnings, it prints just ss.

Comment: @R.Naired I get two warnings from `clang 8.0.0`. One about incompatible pointer to integer conversion on the `s` declaration, and another about the mismatch between the format specifier and argument in `printf()`

Comment: What is with the question title? This has nothing to do with scanning or whitespace but basic C syntax.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to make your program compilable, as compilation gives some errors.

1.) `s` must be defined as `char *s` or `char s[]` because `char s` only allows one character to be stored there, and not an array. `char *s` declares a pointer to the string literal and `char s[]` declares an array of characters of as many as present in the string literal and initializes it with the characters of the specified string literal.

2.) `stdin` is a global variable of type `FILE *` (actually it isn't but it behaves as) that represent the standard input.  If you don't declare it, the compiler doesn't know where the `stdin` identifier came from, so it issues an error.  The way to eliminate this second error is to `#include <stdio.h>` which has a definition for it and makes the compiler happy.

Once you do these two steps, your program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char s[]= "StackOverflow ";
    char ss[100]; 
    fgets(ss,100,stdin);
    // i know i can use strcat but i don't want it here
    printf("%s%s",s,ss);
    return 0;
}
```

and behaves as you wanted.